# Why generic array creation works in some circumstances

Tags: java, generics, deque

As well-known, generic array creation is not supported in Java. For example, the following code will error out with `generic array creation` during the build,

```
Deque<TreeNode>[] stacks = {new ArrayDeque(), new ArrayDeque()};
```

However, the following code of creating such an array works,

```
Deque<TreeNode>[] stacks = new ArrayDeque[2];
```

I would like to know the rationale behind why the behaviors are different between these two logic.

Comment: Your second example would fail as well when you wouldn't ignore the generic type of `ArrayDeque`. Java doesn't ignore it in the first example and adds it to the array initializer.

Comment: @Tom At a high level, your explanation makes sense to you. But could you give me an example of how to 'not ignoring the generic type of ArrayDeque' by updating the 2nd code? Another question is, is the 2nd code considered to be a bad practice in Java?

Comment: You seem to already know generic types, since you used them for `Deque<TreeNode>` so updating your code to not ignore in the seconds example should be rather obvious `new ArrayDeque<TreeNode>[2]`.

Comment: @CodingFanSteve not sure if you realised, but the second example will have 2 `null` entries.

Comment: @jbx Yes, when I do the 2nd code pattern, I usually use Arrays.setAll() to initialize the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When they say "[parameterised array creation is not allowed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createArrays)", they mean that this specific syntax is not allowed:

```
new T<U>[]
```

where `T` and `U` are types. Note that this has nothing to do with the *declared type* of the array. It's perfectly fine to *declare* an array to be of type `Deque<TreeNode>`, so the problem is on the right side of the `=`, not the left.

In the second case, you are doing `new ArrayDeque[2]`, obviously not violating the rule, as it is not in the form `new T<U>[]`.

In the first case, you are using an *array initialiser*, making the compiler infer what type of array you are trying to create, and the compiler does so by looking at the left hand side. So the first line is equivalent to:

```
Deque<TreeNode>[] stacks = new Deque<TreeNode>[] {new ArrayDeque(), new ArrayDeque()};
```

which is not allowed. It is in the form `new T<U>[]`.

Comment: @Tom It's basic pattern matching, isn't? I've tried to clarify a bit more. What do you think?

Comment: Well I expected a bit more regarding `ArrayDeque` being a generic type explicitly ignoring the generic and thus deactivating generic type checks for that array altogether. But its fine I guess :D